# passing authorization token to subsequent request using JSON extractor in jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter, access-token, jmeter-5.0

**passing authorization token to subsequent request using JSON extractor in jmeter.**
I have 2 requests

1. Token
2. Get Policy
   Scenario : Generate the token and pass that token in header of 'Get Policy' request.

I have generated token and extracted using JSON extractor (name of the variable is TOKEN)
and Using Debug sampler i verified that bearer token is extracted.
after that i added 'HTTP Header Manager' to the next request. and added Authorization there like

Name = Authorization and Value = ${TOKEN}.

Getting 'Unauthorized access running the script while running the script for second (Get Policy) request.

Answer (score 0):

For Bearer authorization, your header value must be `Bearer YOUR_TOKEN`, you missed Bearer keyword in value and HTTP Header Manager can not understand your authorization method.

```
Name = Authorization and Value = Bearer ${TOKEN}
```

I hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

As per [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1)

> When sending the access token in the "Authorization" request header
> field defined by HTTP/1.1 [[RFC2617]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617), the client uses the "Bearer"
> authentication scheme to transmit the access token.

> For example:

> ```
> GET /resource HTTP/1.1
> Host: server.example.com
> Authorization: Bearer mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM
> ```

So correct configuration of the [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/) would be:

[image]